# Error while pushing file into Android Emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to push a CSV file into emulator in android. But due to following error I cannot push file.
Does anyone have solution for this issue?
Please explain step-by-step.
Thanks in advance.

[2014-04-10 14:47:57 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2014-04-10 14:47:57] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: check your files properties

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows**:

Just go to

`C:\Documents and Settings\<adminstrator>\.android\avd`

take '**properties**' of your avd folder (there is a folder for each of the avd's)

`uncheck 'Read only' -> OK`

For **Linux**:

In a terminal  go to sdk/platform-tools directory (to get access to the adb shell) then  type the following commands:

`./adb shell`

`su`

`mount -o rw,remount rootfs /`

`chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard`

and then typed "**exit**" to exit the adb shell.

Comment: If my answer is useful for you then you can accept my answer. Thanks